# How to sort a dynamic array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have created two empty array in jquery and using ajax I'm assigning the values in them suppose there are `2` values in each array assigned by the ajax but they are randomly placed but I'm populating them with the select option so for displaying it well I have to display that array in the efficient way soo here is my code I'm using but not works:-

Code:-

```
  <select id="dropdown">
  </select>

var array1 = Array();
var array2 = Array();
$.ajax({
    url:"/api/v1/workingspots",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(response){
        for (var i = 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++) {
            array1 = response.response.data[i].start_time;
            array2  = response.response.data[i].end_time;
            var res = array1.sort(function(a, b) {
                  return a > b
                });  
        }
    }
});
```

Error I'm facing :-

```
 Uncaught TypeError: array1.sort is not a function
at Object.success (booking:58)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at A (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
at Object.send (jquery.min.js:4)
at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (booking:49)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

values I'm assigning to array is:-

```
 //By console.log(array1)
 28800
 14400
```

How will I sort both the arrays and assigning there each values produce by both array populate with the select option. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`start_time` is a single value not an collection, so you need to fill the values to the collection and than apply to sort on it,

```
var array1 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++) {
    array1.push({ 
         start_time : response.response.data[i].start_time, 
         end_time: response.response.data[i].end_time
    });             
}
var res = array1.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.start_time > b.start_time
});
```